# Eclipse jar file is not exported with project

Tags: eclipse, jar

I have a simple project that I need to be very easily imported into eclipse and started. When I export my project and import it again it comes with an error saying it is missing a required jar file. This jar file is added to the build path, but does not carry over when the project is exported. Why is this? I have been searching all day for an answer on Google and none have helped.

Would I just have to send the jar file along with the project and have the users manually add it?

Things I have tried:
Going into build path order and export and clicking the jar file.
using a clean workspace for the import / restarting eclipse.

Comment: How do you export it?  Eclipse gives you many options.  Is the JAR selected in the export dialog box that opens?

Comment: Are you exporting it as Jar file and including the jar which eclipse complains on import that it is missing?

Comment: It is being exported as a ICAP Java Archive file (a plugin) and there is no dialog box option to select included jars

Answer (score 1):

For anyone with a future problem like this one. I was putting the jar in the lib folder and also adding it to my build path, but the jar would not export over. When I added the jar to the WEB-INF / lib folder it successfully carried over with the export.

Comment: this worked for me as well. Not sure if the file just needs to be within the project subfolder.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try this:

Right click on the imported project select `Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Java build Path -> Libraries Tab` and check if the jar file which eclipse says missing is present in the Libraries tab.

If it is present then select it and click `Edit`, a "File dialog" will pop up, find the desired jar which is in your computer's directory. and click Ok then wait for eclipse to build 
the workspace. If it is not present then add it through `Add JARs...` or `Add External JARs...`

Comment: Thank you for the answer John. This would definitely work but the point I was making is that I want it as easy as possible for the other people importing my project (they wouldn't have the jar file on their computer to do as you said) I just want them to import the project and have no errors. For this to happen that jar file must be already in place when they import, and it is not.

Answer (score 0):

Export it as an Archive file of the project rather than a jar.  Then it's just a matter of someone else importing it as an Existing Project.  Exporting it as a jar is only something you do when you want to deploy the jar and run it.